# Execute command from Spigot in BungeeCord

Tags: java, bukkit

I need execute command from Spigot in BungeeCord, but I don't know how to. I use a more function... for example Forward Channel, Message Channel, BungeeCord.getInstance().dispatchCommand, ProxyServer.getInstance().dispatchCommand. None of this options not work. By the way BungeeCord[..].dispatchCommand i ProxyServer send error in console. I use BungeeCord API in a first time. I was looking for more options, maybe I used a bad api.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the Messaging Channels directly from Spigot and send information to BungeeCord with that.

Here is a little example on how you want to do this :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(b);
    try {
        out.writeUTF("Message");
        out.writeUTF("ALL");
        out.writeUTF("/alert Testing command distance");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    p.sendPluginMessage(getPlugin(), "BungeeCord", b.toByteArray());
```

You can of course change the information you want to send, here is the official wiki about messaging channels : https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bukkit-bungee-plugin-messaging-channel/#message

PS: You have to register the Channel in your onEnable()

```
this.getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");
```